# How to turn off live video on the right on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

Twitter keeps on showing me "Live video" on the right column, usually with some sports or esports.

Right now I keep seeing "Wimbledon live". Even when I click on "Hide", on reload, I see it again.

I have never shown interest in tennis or Wimbledon, and I have no idea how it's related to Twitter at all.

How do I turn it off? I have searched Twitter documentation and settings, and I don't see anything about these live videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on *Profile & Settings* (top right avatar image) then *Settings and privacy*.  In the section *Content* there is a checkbox labeled *Video Tweets*: *Video autoplay*. Uncheck it, *Save* and voila, Live videos are gone.